# Custom Property in the Texture Node Editor

Tags: node-editor, sculpting

I'm trying to build a Custom Sculpting Mesh with advanced properties, which would ideally be changeable in either the Sculpting Window or the Texture Properties Panel.
I want these custom properties to change the value of a MixRGB node in the Texture Node Editor, but this editor doesn't seem to support using drivers.

Anyone have suggestions on how I could implement something like this?

Comment: Maybe this video helps: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=asGV_CuO2hc

Comment: The problem is that Drivers don't work in the Texture Node Editor